# Google Sheets - How to concatenate values from different rows and columns if the cells meet certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a formula that concatenates cell values if the ticked box is TRUE Please see attached image [click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIqIz.png)

What I am trying to do is to concatenate in one string columns B and C from every row if the checkbox in column A is selected, and have them separated by a ",". You can in cell G2 an example of the final result I am trying to achieve.

You can find the google sheet in this link  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hwm4Q89qj3ko2vJ4OASWmgz4VQr_uUaP7E7AmVdl8Ks/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(A4:A,B4:C,)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sheet formula first.

```
=IF(A4="","",IF(A4=TRUE,TEXTJOIN(",",True,B4,C4),""))
```

This formula has nested IF's just for additional checker to check if the first column has a value and would return blank just for it to be dynamic. You can drag the formula down to adjust the cells.

**Sheet sample:**

[image]